# Can find imported Spring beans from JAR, but not from WAR

Tags: spring, rest, maven, jar, war

My application consists of three Maven projects (I am omitting other modules)): FrameworkBase (JAR), FrameworkBaseImpl (JAR), FrameworkRestService (WAR).

FrameworkRestService is a plugin to FrameworkBaseImpl, drawing its class/interface definitions
from FrameworkBase, which FrameworkBaseImpl implements/extends. (I had to split FrameworkBase to avoid Maven curcular dependencies).

FrameworkBaseImpl has a main, which invokes Jetty, passing the FrameworkRestService war.

I am trying to have Spring inject a RestService instance as a field member in the (sole) instance of FrameworkMain class of FrameworkBaseImpl. My Spring points to FrameworkRestService class inside FrameworkRestService project as implementing the restService bean.

And here is the problem: Although Spring seems to find the imported framework_rest_service.context file in the WAR that contains the bean it fails injecting it (no bean named restService is found). But if I convert FrameworkRestService into a JAR - it magically succeeds! I am stuck for 2 days on it! Please help!

FrameworkBase pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>framework.base</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>framework.base</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <parent>
    <groupId>controlapps</groupId>
    <artifactId>controlapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../controlapp/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>
</project>
```

FrameworkBase RestService:

```
package com.company.controlapps.framework.base;

public class RestService {
    public FrameworkMain frameworkMain;

    /* Setters for Spring */
    public void setFrameworkMain(FrameworkMain frameworkMain) 
            {this.frameworkMain = frameworkMain;}
}
```

FrameworkBase FrameworkMain:

```
package com.company.controlapps.framework.base;

public interface FrameworkMain {    
...
}
```

FrameworkBaseImpl pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>framework.base.impl</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>framework.base.impl</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <parent>
    <groupId>controlapps</groupId>
     <artifactId>controlapp</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <relativePath>../controlapp/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
    <groupId>controlapps</groupId>
    <artifactId>framework.base</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>controlapps</groupId>
     <artifactId>framework.restservice</artifactId>
     <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
     <type>war</type>       
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

FrameworkBaseImpl FrameworkMainImpl:

```
package com.company.controlapps.framework.base.impl;

public class FrameworkMainImpl implements FrameworkMain {
    ....
    protected RestService restService;
    public void setRestService(RestService restService) 
        {this.restService = restService;}
}

public static void main(String[] args) {        
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(SPRING_CONTEXT_FILENAME);
    FrameworkMainImpl frameworkMain = (FrameworkMainImpl) context.getBean("frameworkMain");
        ...
}
```

FrameworkBaseImpl spring context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="classpath*:framework_restservice_context.xml"/>

    <bean id="frameworkMain" class="com.company.controlapps.framework.base.impl.FrameworkMainImpl" >
    <property name="restService" ref="restService" />
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

FrameworkRestService FrameworkRestService pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>framework.restservice</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>framework.restservice</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jersey.version>1.12</jersey.version>
  </properties>

  <parent>
    <groupId>controlapps</groupId>
    <artifactId>controlapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../controlapp/pom.xml</relativePath>
  </parent>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>controlapps</groupId>
      <artifactId>framework.base</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
       <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
       <artifactId>jersey-server-linking</artifactId>
       <version>${jersey.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

FrameworkRestService spring framework_restservice_context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean id="restService" class="com.radware.controlapps.framework.restservice.FrameworkRestService">
    <property name="frameworkMain" ref="frameworkMain" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

FrameworkRestService FrameworkRestService.java snippet:

```
package com.company.controlapps.framework.restservice;

@Path("myresource")
public class FrameworkRestService extends RestService {
    ... 
    @Context
    UriInfo uriInfo;
    @Context
    Request request;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public MyResource getMyResource() {
    ...
    frameworkMain.doSomething();
    ....
}
```

Sorry for the long question. :-)

Comment: Your war pom only has a dependency on the framework.base jar, should it not be a dependency on the framework.base.impl jar instead???

Comment: Quite sure it's a classloader issue. Have no idea of classloading policies for the way you run the stuff  "FrameworkBaseImpl has a main, which invokes Jetty, passing the FrameworkRestService war. ???"

Comment: Dependencies: the war has compile time dependency on framework.base jar; framework.base.impl has runtime dependency on the war (sort of plugin). I started with using framework.base only with the war having compile time dependency on base, and base having run time dependency on the war. Maven did not accept it, saying circular dependency. Yeah, right. The problem is that Maven does not distinguish between types of dependencies in calculating circles... That is why I had to re-factor my code into framework.base.impl and framework.base maven projects in order to break this "circular dependency".

Comment: Classloader: have not tried to look into it. Could be it. Will try and post if found anything.

Comment: It wasn't a class loader issue. I had the WAR and the JAR use the same class loader (of the JAR). Somebody commented that I shouldn't have tried to link a WAR and look for beans in there. So instead of trying to solve the problem I simply bypassed it by canceling Spring dependencies between the JAR and the WAR. In the WAR I still needed a reference to the FrameworkMain singleton instantiated in the JAR. I "hacked" this as follows: I added a class named Holder with public static methods get and set the FrameworkMain instance singleton. I call get from the WAR, and set from the jar. Thanks.

Comment: I could not add this to FrameworkMain, which is actually an interface in FrameworkBase jar (implemented by FrameworkMainImpl in the FrameworkBaseImpl jar).

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't a class loader issue. I had the WAR and the JAR use the same class loader (of the JAR). Somebody commented that I shouldn't have tried to link a WAR and look for beans in there.

So instead of trying to solve the problem I simply bypassed it by canceling Spring dependencies between the JAR and the WAR. In the WAR I still needed a reference to the FrameworkMain singleton instantiated in the JAR.

I "hacked" this as follows: I added a class named Holder with public static methods get and set the FrameworkMain instance singleton. I call get from the WAR, and set from the jar. I could not add this to FrameworkMain, which is actually an interface in FrameworkBase jar (implemented by FrameworkMainImpl in the FrameworkBaseImpl jar).

Thanks.